# How to run a php code with amazon rds instance?

Tags: php, postgresql-9.3

So i have successfully, created a db instance with minimum security,database is postgres, and pgadmin4 is showing my remote db instance, i also have created a table in my db instance using that pgadmin, and the dbinstance log has shown the changes made. Now how to run a php script for a simple database operation? where should i paste the .php file ? Like what to do after this?

Comment: This really has little to do with RDS.

Comment: ya sorry for wrong headline, but now how to execute a php code? I am new at this..

Comment: my friend told me to try copying them to s3 .

Comment: Find a new friend for PHP advice, then.

Comment: do you have any answer for me?

Comment: Frankly, I'd go with some managed hosting of some sort. On AWS you largely have to set things up from scratch, i.e. provision and configure a server on EC2. You'd be better off with a hosting provider that gives you a ready-to-go VPS with PHP already installed, or a service like Heroku.

Comment: Thanks a ton, i'll give this a try.